# How to get radius of the RenderObject in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have screen where show showcase screen component. Now these components can be anything and I want to dynamically find radius of the widget. Which I will pass to a custom painter to draw that shape with radius.

I have tried using finding anything useful in RenderObject but haven't found anything.

Is there any method which can provide me `RRect` object similar to below?

```
    final box = globalKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    final rect = size & box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
```

Comment: widget does not have a radius concept - you cannot get a radius from a `RenderBox` since this has nothing to do with radius (you can get a `Size` however)

Comment: @pskink Yeah I was just thinking that renderbox wouldn't contain any shape related properties and would just contain size and position.

Comment: @pskink I resolved it by context.widget and going deep in the widget tree this way

Answer (score 0):

A RenderObject will not be disposed until you replace it by another RenderObject of a different type, or remove the associated widget from the widget tree.

Comment: how is this related to my question?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using context.widget like this,

```
double getRadius() {
    BuildContext? context = key!.currentContext;
    var parent = context?.widget;
    if (parent is Parent) {
      var gestureDetector = (parent).child;
      if (gestureDetector is GestureDetector) {
        var clipRRect = gestureDetector.child;
        if (clipRRect is ClipRRect) {
          return (clipRRect.borderRadius as BorderRadius).topRight.x;
        }
      }
    }
 return 0;
}
```